# Do I need to apply a Ranking Algorithm for this?

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, predictive-modeling, ranking

I have data of the form :

```
Id1      A_Id2      B_Id2       C_Id2       D_Id2      E_Id2      F_Id2
1         6           3           9           23         20         5
1         4           7           8           9          11         56                                                   
1         2           36          98          73         2          4     
1         9           5           2           7          32         24           
1         14          7           5           9          12         5                                                   
2         34          4           7           10          7         12                                                       
2         5           57          23          91          4         6                                                    
2         7           .           .           .           .         .
2         3           .           .           .           .         .
2         .           .           .           .           .         .
.
.
100      .            .           .           .           .         .
```

Basically, I want to build a model such that I can get a best match of Id1, given top 5 Id2 matches of each attribute(A_Id2, B_Id2,...,F_Id2). Now every match should be computed keeping in mind A has highest priority, followed by B and C, followed by D and least priority to E and F.

So the output will look like this :

```
Id1    Match_Id2
1        9
2        7
3        .
4        .
```

I hope the problem is clear, if not please ask.
How should I go about building a Machine Learning model for this? I was wondering if ranking algorithm will help ?

Comment: what do you mean by 'top 5 Id2 matches of each attribute'. Can you modify your output so that match values are correct too

Comment: @device_exec output is edited. top 5 attributes are preferences by each attribute.